# Efficient algorithm for merging consistent rows of multiple 2d arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have an arbitrary number of 2d arrays of equal width but possibly non-equal height. They can consist of 1s, 0s, or a wildcard `*` which can match either a 1 or a 0. The wildcards are always in the same columns. I want to return all possible rows that are consistent with at least one row in *every* array simultaneously, and contain no wild cards.

For a concrete example, consider the three 2d arrays

```
     1 0 1 *        * 0 1 0        * 1 * 1    
a =  1 1 1 *   b =  * 1 1 0   c =  * 0 * 0
     0 1 0 *        * 0 0 1
```

A possible row in the solution might be `1 0 1 0`. It is consistent with the top row of `a`, the top row of `b`, and the second row of `c`. By contrast, a row that should *not* be in the solution is `0 1 0 1`, since it is not consistent with any row of `b` despite being consistent with the bottom row of `a` and the top row of `c`.

Beyond doing an inefficient brute-force check I'm rather stuck. It seems like there should be a faster way. Are there are any tricks that might help solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: How do you define the wildcards in your numpy array?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal OP didn't mention either Python or numpy...

Comment: ah apologies, just saw that this is a generic algorithm tag and not python.

Comment: Yeah this is supposed to be language-agnostic. In my original problem the wildcard columns don't exist and each array has an associated indexing array that maps the column to their proper positions, but I thought the question would be easier to understand this way, with the wildcards. The context is combining solutions from a system of equations where equations share variables.

Comment: Choose the most restrictive column. Set it to 0, recurse. Set it to 1, recurse. In the example, choose the 2nd column. After setting it to 0, there's only 1 row left for `a`, 2 for `b` and 1 for `c`. After setting it to 1, there are 2 rows for `a`, 1 for `b` and 1 for `c`.

Comment: What is the max width of your matrix? For simplicity, let's consider there are at most 64 columns in this problem. Then, for each row you can form a number with those 64 bits (as there are only `0` and `1` in the matrix cell). You can use any efficient data structure to store those numbers so that you can search for an existence in O(1). Now create such a data structure one for each matrix. If any row have any wildcard, consider both `0` and `1` for that position. For example, for `1 0 ?`, you should consider both `1 0 0` and `1 0 1`.

Comment: The overall complexity of this approach should be O(number_of_all_rows * columns). But, you can do that only if you have maximum of 64 columns in your matrix. For higher number of columns, you can consider hashing based solution. Similar to the previous approach, instead of creating a number ... create the hash of that number.